# What if cosmological inflation never stopped?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang, cosmological-inflation

If inflantionary theory is correct, the universe ceased to expand after just $10^{−32}$
seconds. Imagine a scenario where cosmic inflation never actually stopped.

At the extremely accelerated expansion rates of inflation (which incresead the size of the universe by a factor of $10^{26}$) How much time would have taken for the universe to reach the size of the currently observable universe?

How much time until the Big Rip in this scenario?

What would the universe look like today?

Comment: If you read carefully https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)#Eternal_inflation you will see that there are a number of models.

Comment: Well it would be a de-Sitter Universe. I guess you can calculate that by using the conformal time equation and taking $a(t) \propto e^{Ht}$